# How to place caption centered under a table

Tags: tables, captions

I am trying to place a caption underneath the table to be centered in a two columned document. I want the table to be on top of the page and the first thing to come after the chapter title. So far I was able to place the table in the middle but the caption is as wide as the columns.
Here is the code that I have:

```
\chapter{Results \& Discussion}\label{chapter:Results}
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:

\begin{table}[]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcccc@{}}
\toprule
                 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Male}}         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Female}}       \\ \midrule
\textbf{Anatomy} & \textbf{Min. force} & \textbf{Max. force} & \textbf{Min. force} & \textbf{Max. force} \\ \midrule
Thyroid          & 2.32 $\pm$ 2.33      & 6.57 $\pm$ 1.84      & 1.8 $\pm$ 0.96       & 4.56 $\pm$ 1.74      \\ \midrule
Forearm artery   & 3.34 $\pm$ 1.5       & 8.04 $\pm$ 1.95      & 2.2 $\pm$ 1.17       & 6.58 $\pm$ 2.19      \\ \midrule
Calf muscles     & 1.67 $\pm$ 1.29      & 4.8 $\pm$ 1.5        & 1.33 $\pm$ 0.86      & 4.2 $\pm$ 0.95       \\ \midrule
Vertebrae        & 7.36 $\pm$ 4.19      & 27.83 $\pm$ 3.84     & 5.8 $\pm$ 4.82       & 23 $\pm$ 9.55        \\ \midrule
Abdominal aorta  & 7.19 $\pm$ 5.66      & 17.56 $\pm$ 7.54     & 8.47 $\pm$ 3         & 18.91$\pm$ 3.85      \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Recorded minimum and maximum forces for all anatomies and gender. All forces measured in newtons.}
\label{tab:forceResults}
\end{table}
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

I want the caption of this table be basically the same width as the picture and not go to a separate line.

Comment: In a two-column document you would normally use `table*` to get a wide table spanning the two columns, otherwise the text of the other column may interfere. That will also give a wide caption. And it is strongly advised **not** to use `\resizebox`.

Comment: you have a full width table overprinting the second column, any following text will over-print the table and be unreadable, you should make the table `\columnwidth` not `\textwidth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a two-column document that uses the `multicol` package (Chapter 1 in the example), then you temporarily end the two-column environment, start  in one-column mode, add the tabular, and resume two columns.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage{caption}% needed for captionof

\usepackage{booktabs}% rules
\usepackage{multicol}% two columns <<<

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % ONLY dummy text

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \chapter{Method}
            \kant[1-3] 
            \chapter{Results \& Discussion}\label{chapter:Results}          
    \end{multicols} % now start one column <<<<<<<<<<<<     

  \noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}lcccc@{}}
                \toprule
                & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Male}}     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Female}}       \\ \midrule
                \textbf{Anatomy} & \textbf{Min. force} & \textbf{Max. force} & \textbf{Min. force} & \textbf{Max. force} \\ \midrule
                Thyroid          & 2.32 $\pm$ 2.33      & 6.57 $\pm$ 1.84      & 1.8 $\pm$ 0.96       & 4.56 $\pm$ 1.74      \\ \midrule
                Forearm artery   & 3.34 $\pm$ 1.5       & 8.04 $\pm$ 1.95      & 2.2 $\pm$ 1.17       & 6.58 $\pm$ 2.19      \\ \midrule
                Calf muscles     & 1.67 $\pm$ 1.29      & 4.8 $\pm$ 1.5        & 1.33 $\pm$ 0.86      & 4.2 $\pm$ 0.95       \\ \midrule
                Vertebrae        & 7.36 $\pm$ 4.19      & 27.83 $\pm$ 3.84     & 5.8 $\pm$ 4.82       & 23 $\pm$ 9.55        \\ \midrule
                Abdominal aorta  & 7.19 $\pm$ 5.66      & 17.56 $\pm$ 7.54     & 8.47 $\pm$ 3         & 18.91$\pm$ 3.85      \\ \bottomrule
            \end{tabular*}
    \captionof{figure}{Recorded minimum and maximum forces for all anatomies and gender. All forces measured in newtons.\label{tab:forceResults}}                       

    \begin{multicols}{2} % restart two column
    \kant[1-2]  
    \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Using instead

```
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \chapter{Method}
            \kant[1-3] 
    \end{multicols} % now start one column <<<<<<<<<<<<
    
    \chapter{Results \& Discussion}\label{chapter:Results}
```

will make

[image: b]

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the optional argument of `\twocolumn` to add full page stuff at the top of a page.  The problem is that `\chapter` already does it, and you can only do it once per page.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}% for \captionof

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{plain}%
\twocolumn[\vbox{\csname @twocolumnfalse\endcsname
  \csname @chapter\endcsname[Results \& Discussion]{Results \& Discussion}\label{chapter:Results}}
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcccc@{}}
\toprule
                 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Male}}         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Female}}       \\ \midrule
\textbf{Anatomy} & \textbf{Min. force} & \textbf{Max. force} & \textbf{Min. force} & \textbf{Max. force} \\ \midrule
Thyroid          & 2.32 $\pm$ 2.33      & 6.57 $\pm$ 1.84      & 1.8 $\pm$ 0.96       & 4.56 $\pm$ 1.74      \\ \midrule
Forearm artery   & 3.34 $\pm$ 1.5       & 8.04 $\pm$ 1.95      & 2.2 $\pm$ 1.17       & 6.58 $\pm$ 2.19      \\ \midrule
Calf muscles     & 1.67 $\pm$ 1.29      & 4.8 $\pm$ 1.5        & 1.33 $\pm$ 0.86      & 4.2 $\pm$ 0.95       \\ \midrule
Vertebrae        & 7.36 $\pm$ 4.19      & 27.83 $\pm$ 3.84     & 5.8 $\pm$ 4.82       & 23 $\pm$ 9.55        \\ \midrule
Abdominal aorta  & 7.19 $\pm$ 5.66      & 17.56 $\pm$ 7.54     & 8.47 $\pm$ 3         & 18.91$\pm$ 3.85      \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\captionof{table}{Recorded minimum and maximum forces for all anatomies and gender. All forces measured in newtons.}
\label{tab:forceResults}
\vskip\intextsep]

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A hack, but, hey, it works!

Set the table *in the chapter title*.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{uncertainty-mode = separate}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}
\chapter[Results and Discussion]{%
  Results and Discussion\label{chapter:Results}\\[4ex]
  \normalsize\normalfont
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
    @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    l
    S[table-format=1.2(2)]
    S[table-format=2.2(2)]
    S[table-format=1.2(2)]
    S[table-format=2.2(2)]
    @{}
  }
  \toprule
  \textbf{Anatomy} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Male}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Female}} \\
  \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5}
  &
  {\textbf{Min.\ force}} &
  {\textbf{Max.\ force}} &
  {\textbf{Min.\ force}} &
  {\textbf{Max.\ force}} \\
  \midrule
  Thyroid          & 2.32 \pm 2.33 &  6.57 \pm 1.84 & 1.8  \pm 0.96 &  4.56 \pm 1.74 \\
  Forearm artery   & 3.34 \pm 1.5  &  8.04 \pm 1.95 & 2.2  \pm 1.17 &  6.58 \pm 2.19 \\
  Calf muscles     & 1.67 \pm 1.29 &  4.8  \pm 1.5  & 1.33 \pm 0.86 &  4.2  \pm 0.95 \\
  Vertebrae        & 7.36 \pm 4.19 & 27.83 \pm 3.84 & 5.8  \pm 4.82 & 23    \pm 9.55 \\
  Abdominal aorta  & 7.19 \pm 5.66 & 17.56 \pm 7.54 & 8.47 \pm 3    & 18.91 \pm 3.85 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}\\
  \captionof{table}{Recorded minimum and maximum forces 
    for all anatomies and gender. All forces measured in
    newtons.\label{tab:forceResults}
  }
}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

No `\resizebox` and yes `siunitx`. With `tabular*` you can make the table to the text width.

[image]